# PHP what is wrong with this code?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I am quite new to php and am having problems with the following block of code.  For some reason when all has been executed i am being sent to: auctionx.php?id=".  When it should be id=1.  I am trying to get the "1" from the $new_id variable.  Could somebody please point out my error?  Thanks a lot in advance.  P.S When i've got my project sorted, as regards functionality, i will then make what i am told is a sensible translation to mysqli.  Thanks again.

Oh, and one last thing, i am conscious there may well be a short cut i am missing.  After the INSERT query is there anyway some code could know straightaway what the new id is, if you know what i mean? To save me doing the next query.  Is it as simply as having "$new_id" in the first value field.  Hope that is clear.

```
if ($check_1 == 0)
{

//Then need to register the auction...so...

$auc_update = mysql_query("

INSERT INTO auction VALUES ('','$afil','$user','','','','','')

//Should the first be "$new_id" here (above) i mean


");

$row_1 = mysql_query("

SELECT * FROM auction WHERE host = $user AND auc_no = $afil  

");

//Find
$new_id = $row_1['id'];

//Id obtained
//Go to:

header ("location:auctionx.php?id='$new_id'");

}
```

Comment: You are not doing any error checking after your queries, so you will never receive a hint about what goes wrong. See the manual on how to do that properly: http://php.net/mysql_query

Comment: ... and the way you are fetching the data is incorrect. You should probably work through a basic tutorial to see how this is done.

Comment: **Heads up!** Future versions of PHP are *deprecating and removing* the `mysql_` family of functions. It looks like you're new to PHP, so now would be a great time to [switch to PDO](http://php.net/book.pdo) or [mysqli](http://php.net/book.mysqli).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you miss one `mysql_xxx()` function call. `mysql_query()` simply sends the query to mysql but for a `SELECT` you then need to retrieve the results like this :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM auction WHERE host = $user AND auc_no = $afil");
$row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$new_id = $row1['id'];
header ("Location: auctionx.php?id=$new_id");
```

More information on the function used :
[mysql_query()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) [mysql_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Then you really should ensure that your query works so check the return value and check if it is not false, else display an error :

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM auction WHERE host = $user AND auc_no = $afil");
if(false == $result) {
    echo "Mysql error '" . mysql_errno() . "' : " . mysql_error();
}
```

Then, it seems that what you want is to retrieve the id associated with the last insertion in your database. You don't need a `SELECT` for this, just use [mysql_insert_id()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php) for this.

With all this in mind your code would become:

```
if ($check_1 == 0)
{
$auc_update = mysql_query("INSERT INTO auction VALUES ('','$afil','$user','','','','','')");
if(false == $auc_update ) {
    echo "Mysql error '" . mysql_errno() . "' : " . mysql_error();
} else {
    $new_id = mysql_insert_id();
    header ("Location: auctionx.php?id=$new_id");
}
```

And another thing, `mysql_xxx()` are considered deprecated, you really should avoid using it and try [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdo.php) instead.

Comment: Ha oh yeah.  Cheers.  I've used that plenty of times but clearly completely forgot.  That should do it.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: I added some more info to change your code

Comment: Thanks a lot.  Yeah i was concerned about the possible superfluousness of that bit.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Find
$new_id = $row_1['id'];
```

Try adding `mysql_fetch_assoc()` to `new_id` like:

```
$new_id = mysql_fetch_assoc($row_1)['id'];
```

Answer (score 1):

After `mysql_query()` you must retrieve the result set with [`mysql_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

```
$result_1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM auction WHERE host = $user AND auc_no = $afil");
$row_1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_1);
$new_id = $row_1['id'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntax error: You tried to put a comment inside of a sql statement. Additionally, you need to fetch the row after calling:

```
<?php
if ($check_1 == 0){

    //Then need to register the auction...so...

    $auc_update = mysql_query("INSERT INTO auction VALUES ('','$afil','$user','','','','','')");

    //Should the first be "$new_id" here (above) i mean

    $row_1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM auction WHERE host = $user AND auc_no = $afil ");
    $row_1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($row_1);
    //Find
    $new_id = $row_1['id'];

    //Id obtained
    //Go to:

    header ("location:auctionx.php?id='$new_id'");
}?>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### The problem is here:

```
$new_id = $row_1['id'];
```

You should do `mysqli_fetch_array()` before you do this.

---

#### Just a suggestion:

It is better to use PDO or `mysqli_*` instead of `mysql_`.